# ./configure pcsc_cflags when trying to install acs driver for ACR122U in opensuse

Tags: opensuse, pcsc, acr122

I'm trying to use the ACR-122U NFC reader and I started with a clean install of Opensuse. I grabbed the c/c++ pattern packages and verified i had

- pcsclite 1.8.3 or above
- libusb 1.0.8 or above
- flex
- perl
- pkg-config

which is called out in the Readme of the PC/SC Driver Package linked below

http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/

When I try to run `./configure`, I get the following result

```
...
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking ifdhandler.h usability... no
checking ifdhandler.h presence... no
checking for ifdhandler.h... no
configure: error: install pcsc-lite 1.8.3 or later, or use ./configure PCSC_CFLAGS=...
```

running `zypper info pcsc-lite` yields:

```
Reading installed packages...

Information for package pcsc-lite:

Repository: openSUSE-13.2-Update
Name: pcsc-lite
Version: 1.8.11-4.4.1
Arch: x86_64
Vendor: openSUSE
Installed: Yes
Status: up-to-date
Installed Size: 138.6 KiB
Summary: PCSC Smart Cards Library
```

Any idea on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Derp, I needed the `pcsc-lite-devel` package.

Answer (score 1):

I needed `libpcsclite-dev` on ubuntu 18.04